# Is there any way of getting mysql result from one table like this?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table "offers" as follows,

```
pid | sellerid | offer
1   |    1     |  30
1   |    2     |  32
1   |    3     |  31
2   |    2     |  60
3   |    3     |  45
```

I want result as follows,

```
pid | seller1price | seller2price | seller3price
1   |      30      |      32      |     31
2   |      --      |      60      |     --
3   |      --      |      --      |     45
```

If record not found it can replaced by 0 or just -. I tried following and many other ways but not getting empty values

```
  select a.pid as pid, a.offer as seller1price, b.offer as seller2price, c.offer as seller3price from offers as a,  offers as b,  offers as c where a.pid=b.pid and b.pid=c.pid group by a.pid;
```

But this skipping empty records and getting only first record. I tried joins but failed too.

any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For known set of elements you can easily generate the pivot, however for unknown set you need to use dynamic sql.

Lets say you have known set of `sellerid` and are `1,2,3` you can do as

```
select
pid,
max(case when sellerid = 1 then offer end) as seller1price,
max(case when sellerid = 2 then offer end) as seller2price,
max(case when sellerid = 3 then offer end) as seller3price
from offers
group by pid;
```

But if you do not know how many values will be then need to use dynamic sql as

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when sellerid = ''',
     sellerid,
      ''' then offer end) AS ',
      concat('seller',sellerid,'price')
    )
  ) into @sql
from offers ;

set @sql = concat('select pid, ', @sql, ' from offers
                  group by pid
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Here is a **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/766e3/3)** with both type of example